# How to get an object from an array that is only 1 word and does not contain any special characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

How do I get the list of only 1 word from wordnet without special characters included?
I'm trying to make it like:

```js
const wordnet = require('wordnet')
await wordnet.init();

  let results = await wordnet.list();

    const words = results.filter(m=> m.includes("raine"))

//array = ["capital of the ukraine", "rainer maria rilke", "cross of lorraine", "straight-grained", "quiche lorraine", "coarse-grained", "featherbrained", "pebble-grained", "scatterbrained",  "toilet-trained", "unrestrainedly", "animal trainer", "lorraine cross", "trained worker", "close-grained", "cross-grained"]

message.channel.send(`${words}`)
```

```js
//expected output: ["featherbrained", "scatterbrained", "unrestrainedly"]
```

I know that this can be done using RegExp but I don't know how. I need help.

Comment: special characters means here?

Comment: means, `!@$%^-`etc. In the array, there are words with `-`. I wanted to get all 1 word's excluding words with `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for alphabet characters first.

```js
const
    array = ["capital of the ukraine", "rainer maria rilke", "cross of lorraine", "straight-grained", "quiche lorraine", "coarse-grained", "featherbrained", "pebble-grained", "scatterbrained", "toilet-trained", "unrestrainedly", "animal trainer", "lorraine cross", "trained worker", "close-grained", "cross-grained"],
    words = array.filter(m => /^[a-z]+$/i.test(m) && m.includes("raine"));

console.log(words);
```

Another approach by using the string and building a regular expression from it.

```js
const
    array = ["capital of the ukraine", "rainer maria rilke", "cross of lorraine", "straight-grained", "quiche lorraine", "coarse-grained", "featherbrained", "pebble-grained", "scatterbrained", "toilet-trained", "unrestrainedly", "animal trainer", "lorraine cross", "trained worker", "close-grained", "cross-grained"],
    word = 'raine',
    wordR = new RegExp(`^[a-z]*${word}[a-z]*$`, 'i'),
    words = array.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, wordR);

console.log(words);
```

Comment: Note that `foo_raine_123` will also match, as `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: now only character are allowed.